# Split number into equal sized groups

Tags: c#, math

Using this example:

```
var amount = x;
var maxPerGroup = y;
var amountGroups = Ceiling(amount/maxPerGroup);
```

Can someone help me how to split the Amount into AmountGroups with a max amount per group of maxAmount? 
These groups have to be almost the same size.

For example:
    amount = 45;
    maxPerGroup = 15;
    amountGroups = 3;

Result: 15 15 15

I am using C# as language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for the arithmetical division operator?

Comment: I just want to seperate an amount into equal sized groups.

Comment: If you divide an integer by an integer (C#, Integer Division), the result is always an integer... what happens if you ceil that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**
not exact c# just to give you the idea.

I think you are looking for a way to grammatically divide a number in different groups. Without knowing how big the groups are and a random amount of groups.

so let's say x = 30 y = 15. 30/15 = 3 groups of 15 and let's say x= 43 so the number should be like ? 14 14 15

```
groups (since you already have this calculated correctly)(should be a double)
//   maxPerGroup = y
membersPerGroup = floor(amount/groups)



List a = new List
//Is the leftover value of the modulus
leftover = amount%groups;
//Loops for each group
for(int i=0;i<groups;i++){


//If there is a left over value
if(leftover>0){
  a.Add(membersPerGroup +1);
  leftover--;
}else{
  a.Add(membersPerGroup );
}

}
```

**I could write in proper c# but It seems that you found the proper code for it**

Comment: As I tried to hint in my comment (question) - the number of groups are not calculated correctly, dividing an integer by an integer will result in an integer (c#). For example 31 divided by 15 returns 2 and ceiling that will get you nowhere....

Comment: It should be a double. Maybe I missed it with writing not so real c# code. But It should have been a double and I guess that's what he ment

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways of splitting the amount between groups. It all depends on whether the only factor is the number of groups or if there are any other factors. See:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list1 = Split1(48, 15); // result is: 15, 15, 15, 3
        List<int> list2 = Split2(48, 15); // result is 12, 12, 12, 12
    }

    public static List<int> Split1 (int amount, int maxPerGroup)
    {
        int amountGroups = amount / maxPerGroup;

        if (amountGroups * maxPerGroup < amount)
        {
            amountGroups++;
        }

        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountGroups; i++)
        {
            result.Add(Math.Min(maxPerGroup, amount));
            amount -= Math.Min(maxPerGroup, amount);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static List<int> Split2 (int amount, int maxPerGroup)
    {
        int amountGroups = amount / maxPerGroup;

        if (amountGroups * maxPerGroup < amount)
        {
            amountGroups++;
        }

        int groupsLeft = amountGroups;
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        while (amount > 0)
        {
            int nextGroupValue = amount / groupsLeft;
            if (nextGroupValue * groupsLeft < amount)
            {
                nextGroupValue++;
            }
            result.Add(nextGroupValue);
            groupsLeft--;
            amount -= nextGroupValue;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is a great solution! I was just implementing this and noticed a short-circuiting optimisation that can be made. If we know that amount mod groupsLeft == 0, then we can add those straight to the list in one go and avoid iterations like so: 

`if (amount % groupsLeft == 0) { result.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(nextGroupValue, groupsLeft)); return result; }`

Answer (score 3):

```
number of groups := ceiling(total / max group size)
number per group := floor(total / number of groups)
rem = total % number per group
```

You will have `rem` groups with `number per group + 1` and `number of groups - rem` groups with `number per group`.

EDIT: Example:

```
total := 50
max group size := 15
number of groups := ceiling(50 / 15) // 4
number per group := floor(50 / 4) // 12
rem := 50 % 12 // 2
```

2 groups with 13 and 2 with 12.

Comment: It should be clear from my code that the slashes represent proper division, not integer division (otherwise the floor and ceiling operations would be meaningless). Beyond that, the use of any particular datatype is an implementation detail.

Comment: This doesn't work for very large totals compared to the max group size. Consider `total: 50,000,000`, `max block size: 4096`. `number of groups: 12208`, `number per group: 4095`, `rem: 50`. But `50 * 4096 + (12208 - 50) * 4095 = 49,991,810` not `50,000,000`.

Answer (score 1):

simple non-optimized solution:

```
int i = amount;
int j = 0;
int [] groups = new  int[amountGroups];
while(i > 0) {
   groups[j] += 1;
   i--;
   j = (j+1)%amountGroups;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Divide an integer into groups

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> results = DistributeInteger(20, 3).ToList();//output: 7,7,6
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> DistributeInteger(int total, int divider)
        {
            if (divider == 0)
                yield return 0;

            int rest = total % divider;
            double result = total / (double)divider;

            for (int i = 0; i < divider; i++)
            {
                if (rest-- > 0)
                    yield return (int)Math.Ceiling(result);
                else
                    yield return (int)Math.Floor(result);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static int[] DistributeIntoGroups(int sum, int groupsCount)
{
    var baseCount = sum / groupsCount;
    var leftover = sum % groupsCount;
    var groups = new int[groupsCount];

    for (var i = 0; i < groupsCount; i++)
    {
        groups[i] = baseCount;
        if (leftover > 0)
        {
            groups[i]++;
            leftover--;
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // For separating a collection into ranges
    static List<List<T>> Split<T>(List<T> source, int size)
    {
        // TODO: Prepopulate with the right capacity
        List<List<T>> ret = new List<List<T>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += size)
        {
            ret.Add(source.GetRange(i, Math.Min(size, source.Count - i)));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // For separating an int into a Tuple range
    static List<Tuple<int, int>> Split(int source, int size)
    {
        var ret = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < source; i += size)
        {
            ret.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, (i + Math.Min(size, source - i))));
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I wanted to get count from a datagridview (x)
        // and then split into groups based on the 
        // count from a combobox (n). In my example my
        // grid had 1771 rows and was split into: 25 groups
        // (4x of 70 and 21x of 71)

        // Driver code
        int x = myDataGridView.Rows.Count; //1771  
        int n = assemblies_cmbbox.Items.Count; //25

        split(x, n);
        //split(amount, maxPerGroup);
    }

    // Function that prints
    // the required sequence
    private void split(int x, int n)
    {

        // If we cannot split the
        // number into exactly 'N' parts
        if (x < n)
            Debug.WriteLine("-1 ");
        // If x % n == 0 then the minimum
        // difference is 0 and all
        // numbers are x / n
        else if (x % n == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                Debug.WriteLine((x / n) + " ");

        }
        else
        {
            // upto n-(x % n) the values
            // will be x / n
            // after that the values
            // will be x / n + 1
            int zp = n - (x % n);
            int pp = x / n;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                if (i >= zp)
                    Debug.WriteLine((pp + 1) + " ");
                else
                    Debug.WriteLine(pp + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

All credits to Sachin.

Visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-the-number-into-n-parts-such-that-difference-between-the-smallest-and-the-largest-part-is-minimum/

Answer (score -2):

```
int amount = x;
int maxPerGroup = y;
int amountGroups = new int[Ceiling(amount/maxPerGroup)];
for(int i=0; i<maxPerGroup; i++)
{
    if(x>maxPerGroup)
    {
        amountGroups[i]= maxPerGroup;
        x = x-maxPerGroup;
    }
    else
    {
        amountGroups[i] = x;
        x =0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give you 15 15 1 in the case of 31?